# I have just configured a new datasource on jboss

Tags: jboss

And created a new user, I have granted it select/update delete rights on specific tables as required.

Will this be enough to use persistence, or will jboss need admin rights as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't need admin rights.

Easiest answer - try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

No, no need to assign admin rights. It will enough by using persistence.xml

please add following in your persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="abc" transaction-type="JTA"> and 
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/data_source_name</jta-data-source>
```

persistence.xml should like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="abc" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/data_source_name</jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <!-- Map entity classes --> 
           <class> com.packege.classname </class>
        <properties>
    <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"       value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and provide the persistence unit name to createEntityManagerFactory method in Hibernate util class.

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("abc");
```